# How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error indication?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, ram

MemTest86+ (the version included with Ubuntu 13.04) says

```
Failing address: 002f796c48 -    759.5 MB
```

What should I specify in the `memmap` kernel parameter to bypass this area?

I've tried running `memtester 770MB` and it says everything is ok so it doesn't look that the MemTest's indications means an error in the 759.5th MB from the start.

How to interpret this MemTest indication to configure `memmap`?

I have no money to buy new RAM now and the error seems to be single so I hope I can just override it.

Comment: FWIW, the kernel will mark certain pages as being "reserved" if it detects a bad segment but is able to recover. Does the output of "free -m" show powers of two for the totals? I mention this as a way of explaining why memtester can't see the bad RAM but memtest86+ can.

Comment: Doesn't look like powers of two actially: http://i.stack.imgur.com/l86L1.png

Comment: By the time an error is detected ( if you even have ecc ram ), it is generally too late.  Also free -m never reports an even power of two as the bios and kernel both reserve some ram.

Comment: I dream to buy an ECC laptop but could never find any offers available, looks like they don't exist.

Comment: Looks like the kernel also [printk's when it finds a bad page](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=2.6.33) (line 264-265).

Comment: How much RAM do you have in total? `memtester 770MB` doesn't test the first 770MB, but any 770MB it could allocate. Whatever other RAM is still free then isn't tested. The address provided by memtest86+ should be reliable so memmap that if anything.

Comment: The total is  4 GiB, @frostschutz . I've already located the bad DIMM and replaced it actually but the answer to the question still seems interesting to know so I am not going to delete the question.

Comment: Looks like this question was cross posted on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/592870/how-to-blacklist-a-particular-bad-ram-area-in-windows

Comment: Does slm's solution work for you?

Comment: I ask for Windows solutions there and for Linux solutions here, @slm

Comment: I had already got rid of the bad RAM to the time the answer was submitted, @HaukeLaging, so I couldn't check it out (I only approve answers I have tested). I shall test it next time I find a PC with corrupt RAM.

Answer (score 36):

#### memmap

There is this tutorial titled: [Bad Memory HowTo](https://web.archive.org/web/20140806175048/https://bryanquigley.com/planet-ubuntu/bad-memory-howto) which discusses disabling memory via the kernel using the `memmap` argument to the kernel. According to the howto you have 2 options when it comes to `memmap`:

- Turn off everything after the bad memory - `(mem=###M option)`
- Turn off just the memory around the bad memory - `(memmap=#M$###M option)`

With the first option, if memtest reports that there is bad memory at 600M then you could disable the RAM from that point up until the end of RAM with this:

```
 mem=595M
```

If there's bad RAM at 802M and 807M, you can disable a 10M section of RAM starting at 800M like this:

```
memmap=10M$800M
```

**NOTE:** This will blacklist the 10M after the 800M base address. You should run `memtest86+` afterwards to confirm that this argument is correct.

#### BadRAM

There is a patch available for Ubuntu called BadRam. It's covered very well here in this post titled: [BadRAM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM) on the Ubuntu Community site.

After applying the patch to the kernel using the details from that page you make modifications to your Grub2 setup:

*excerpt from that site for Grub2*

> The GRUB2 config file in Natty has a line for configuring kernel bad
>   ram exclusions. So, I will assume that is the preferred way of mapping
>   out a section of memory that is showing errors. The line I set was
>
> GRUB_BADRAM="0x7DDF0000,0xffffc000"
>
> The suggested way on every web site I could find was to set this was
>   to run memtest86 and let it show you the BadRAM settings. memtest86
>   gave me a page of stuff I would have had to enter. I could see that
>   all the addresses were in one 16K block, so I just wanted to map that
>   16K block out of action. Here is how I generated the correct entry.
>
> The first parameter is easy. That is the base address of the bad
>   memory. In my case, I could see that all the bad addresses were
>   greater than 0x7DDF0000 and less than 0x7DDF4000. So, I took the
>   beginning of the 16K block as my starting address.
>
> The second parameter is a mask. You put 1s where the address range you
>   want shares the same values and 0s where it will vary. This means you
>   need to pick your address range such that only the low order bits
>   vary. Looking at my address, the first part of the mask is easy. You
>   want to start with 0xffff. For the next nibble, I will explain with
>   bit maps. I want to range from 0000 to 0011. So, the mask for badram
>   would be 1100 or a hex c. The last 3 nibbles need to be all 0s in the
>   mask, since we want the entire range mapped out. So, we get a total
>   result of 0xffffc000.
>
> After setting this line in /etc/default/grub, I ran sudo update-grub
>   and rebooted and my bad memory was no longer being used. No kernel
>   patches are needed to map out bad memory using this method.

#### Follow up #1

Looking through the wikipedia page for memtest86+ it states as follows:

*excerpt from [Memtest86 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86)*

> Starting from Memtest86 2.3 and Memtest86+ 1.60, the program can
>   output a list of bad RAM regions in the format expected by the BadRAM
>   patch for the Linux kernel; using this information, a Linux system can
>   reliably use a RAM module even if it has a few bad bits. Grub2 is able
>   to supply this same information to an unpatched kernel, negating the
>   need for the BadRAM patch.

Also I came across this [Gentoo page](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-712631-start-0.html) which specified the `memmap=...` using a hex address, so you could specify it like this:

```
memmap=5M$0x2f796c48
```

The 5M is just a guess, obviously you could adjust it lower or higher depending on how much RAM around that region you want/need to omit.

Finally you can specify the size in hex as well:

```
memmap=0x10000$0x2f796c48
```

Would ignore 64KB's starting at address 0x2f796c48.

#### References

- [Understanding Memory](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html)
- [Broken ram and memmap kernel parameter - ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-860631.html)

Comment: "800M to 804M" is supposed to be "800M to 810M" I assume...

Comment: It can be but what I wrote is OK too, even though it's throwing away more memory than the 4M between 800M to 810M.

Comment: 1. I know about the `memmap` option but the question is more about how to interpret the memtest86+ output. I have given a specific example of memtest86+ output and ask for help in configuring `memmap` *accordingly* in this particular case. 2. "You should run memtest86+ afterwards to confirm that this argument is correct." - memtest86+ runs _before_ an OS kernel so I seriously doubt the `memmap` Linux kernel option can affect it.

Comment: @Ivan, 1. I thought it was obvious given the examples I included, but you'd need to say something like: `memmap=5M$759M` for your particular case, given memtest86+ is failing at 759.5MB. 2. I meant that you should pass the `memmap=...` option to memtest86+ as well.   That was untested/unconfirmed by me but something that you may be able to do with memtest86+.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was not sure what does "002f796c48 - 759.5 MB" mean (perhaps it could be 759.5 megs after the 002f796c48 address or something like that) and I have never suspected I can pass Linux kernel parameters to MemTest86+ (I thought it itself was nothing to do with Linux).

Comment: This SU Q&A explains the output better than I could: http://superuser.com/a/326099/20568

Comment: memmap only accepts megabytes, providing address result in parser error and kernel lockup.

Comment: + memtest doesn't seem to accept linux parameters, giving it memmap doesn't do anything, it still tests the memory like if nothing was told to it.

Answer (score 20):

Memtest86+ (I used 4.20) can output a badram format directly.

1. Press 'c' to reach the configuration dialogue 
   [image: memtest configuration dialogue]
2. Then '4' for "Error Report Mode"

   [image: memtest error report mode dialogue]
3. Then '3' for "BadRAM Patterns"

The output will change from a list of individual test failures to a series of badram= lines, each containing one more new bad sector. Because the lines append and coalesce adjacent segments you can just run the test headless overnight and use the final printed line (though if you have a really bad dimm the less-accurate "5 megs around this point" format will likely be quite a bit shorter).

Final result:

[image: Memtest86+ showing badram output]

Comment: Now if I didn't have to copy that over by hand and instead hand it over to GRUB without retyping errors, that would be fantastic.

Comment: What I did is take a photo of it (camera phone), load it up into GIMP, => grayscale => invert => contrast/gamma then hand it to `tesseract ${IMG} stdout` .. then verified and corrected the line before inserting into /etc/default/grub ...
Probably took just as long as manually entering it straight away^^

Comment: Definitely more fun than doing it manually though

Answer (score 5):

Very dirty and very nice work-around: run a user space memtester, wait until it finds an error. Let it, for example, at 0xfce2ea31 .

Then run again memtester, but on that physical address, so:

```
memtester -p 0xfce20000 64k 128
```

To be sure, it is better if you sacrifice more than the page of the problematic address. Here we sacrificed 64kByte around the faulty address.

If all went well, it will find the faulty memory location, far more quickly, again.

**Then suspend the memtester process with a ctrl/z.**

Consequence: until the memtester process is suspended, it won't take away more resource, *but no other process will be able to access the faulty memory*. Because it will be allocated by the memtester.

Particularly useful on big, remote servers. The suspended process can stay until the new RAM is not shipped. Or maybe until the next christmas, when a downtime won't be so big problem.

Comment: Instead of this trick, you can also use the `chmem` tool in util-linux to tell the kernel to take a particular memory range offline (moving the data elsewhere and then never reusing the pages).

Comment: @TooTea I tried this tool on multiple machines, and it could not deactivate a single memory block.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's nice.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Linux 2.6 you can build your kernel with CONFIG_MEMTEST=y

Booting with "memtest" on the kernel command line will then run a quick test of system RAM on every bootup and automatically exclude obvious bad spots.

This won't catch everything since memtest86 is a lot more thorough and runs multiple passes, but it will likely work in the majority of situations, and has the advantage of not requiring manual intervention should you lose another few sectors.