# Does kernel: EDAC MC0: UE page 0x0 point to bad memory, a driver, or something else?

Tags: linux, memory, ram

`kernel: EDAC MC0: UE page 0x0, offset 0x0, grain 0, row 7, labels ":": i3200 UE`

All of a sudden today, our CentOS release 6.4 (Final) system started throwing EDAC errors. I rebooted, and the errors stopped.

I have been searching for answers, but they fall into two camps, memory or a chipset. I would like some advice on where to search further to narrow this down to chipset or memory.

Comment: If it's not a production machine, a memtest would help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're experiencing is an [Error Detection and Correction](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/edac.txt) event. Given the error includes this bit: `MC0` you're experiencing a memory error. This message is telling you where specifically you're experiencing the error. `MC0` means the RAM in the first socket (#0). The rest of that message is telling you specifically within that RAM DIMM the error occurred.

Given you're getting just one, I would continue to monitor it but do nothing for the time being. If it continues then you most likely are experiencing a failing memory module.

You could also try to test it more thoroughly using [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).

This previous question titled: [How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error imdocation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-indicati) will show you how to blacklist the memory if you're interested in that as well.

Comment: For completeness, note that there are interactions between BIOS bugs and the kernel in this area which may lead to spurious results on i32xx chipsets: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=564274