# Issues with grub badram

Tags: debian, grub2, ram

I have a stick of bad memory (the computer randomly segfaults an it gives memtest86+ errors, picture of output at bottom).  As I would like this computer to be working while I work on getting new ram, I would like to use the functionality on grub2 to mask off bad memory.  ([How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error indication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-imdocati/) uses a different method which involves passing arguments to the kernel to do the same thing)

Following the directions from the bottom of [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BadRAM) and the comment in `/etc/defaults/grub` I added the following line to `/etc/defaults/grub`

```
GRUB_BADRAM="0xbfc90044,0xffff80c4,0xb0490444,0xf77f84ec,0xb2490444,0xf27facc4,0xb0492864,0xf07faef4,0xb0490044,0xfd7f91e4,0xb0492144,0xff7fa1c4,0xb0490244,0xf37fe2c4,0xb0494044,0xf3ffc0e4,0xb0493464,0xf17fb4e4,0xb0490044,0xff7fa0c4"
```

which after running `update-grub` added

```
badram 0xbfc90044,0xffff80c4,0xb0490444,0xf77f84ec,0xb2490444,0xf27facc4,0xb0492864,0xf07faef4,0xb0490044,0xfd7f91e4,0xb0492144,0xff7fa1c4,0xb0490244,0xf37fe2c4,0xb0494044,0xf3ffc0e4,0xb0493464,0xf17fb4e4,0xb0490044,0xff7fa0c4
```

to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which seems to correctly match the command line arguments [specified here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#badram).

However, when I re-boot grub does not load, there is just a blank screen.  Booting with a live-disc, commenting out the `badram` line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` allowed me to boot again (but I still have the bad memory un-masked).

I am pretty sure I copied the addresses and masks correctly (had an office mate read the picture to me after I copied it and then I read the file back to them while they were looking at the picture) so I assume I have done something wrong with the formatting, but I do not know what.

[image: memtest86+ output]

Comment: Isn't this the same Q as here? [How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error imdocation?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-imdocati/)

Comment: @slm same goal, but it uses a kernel argument (memmap) rather than instructions to grub.

Comment: OK, that what I thought but I wanted you to double check.

Comment: I did see that thread, probably should have made note of that.  Having grub do it seems more elegant some how.

Answer (score -1):

To use badram option you need [patched](http://rick.vanrein.org/linux/badram/download.html) kernel, and latest patch avaliable only for 2.6.28.

I think you use more recent kernel without that patch, and this is the cause of black screen.

You should use [memmap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-imdocati) option instead of badram.

Comment: no, this is passing the information to `grub` not to the kernel.

Comment: Further, the issue happens before grub has loaded, thus the kernel is not involved at all.