# Automatically memtest and then boot

Tags: linux, boot, memory

Is there some way to reboot server, so it runs memtest (say, 1 or 2 passes) and then reboots back to Linux and writes report to some log?

This feature in Windows Server 2012 helped me to diagnose bad RAM on remote servers couple of times, but I was not able to google any way to do so for Linux server.

Comment: Most servers I have worked with can detect RAM failures without memtest. For example, OpenManage reports these failures on Dell servers.

Comment: @jordanm I agree, but what about cases when hardware platform does not support that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [kernel command-line parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) to test the entire memory as part of the boot sequence and lockout bad blocks. By necessity this *will* add several minutes to your bootup sequence where the box appears unresponsive.

> ```text
> memtest= [KNL,X86,ARM,M68K,PPC,RISCV] Enable memtest
>          Format: <integer>
>          default : 0 <disable>
>          Specifies the number of memtest passes to be
>          performed. Each pass selects another test
>          pattern from a given set of patterns. Memtest
>          fills the memory with this pattern, validates
>          memory contents and reserves bad memory
>          regions that are detected.
> ```

Once you know where the bad blocks are you can avoid them with the `badram=` parameter if the Linux kernel has the [BadRAM](http://rick.vanrein.org/linux/badram/) patch. See also [How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error indication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75059)

There's also the *online* user space memory tester - [**memtester**](https://pyropus.ca./software/memtester/), and you have direct window into your IPMI too (which should be flagging any bad RAM on any half-decent server - on my Intel servers any IPMI-discovered ECC errors have been written into syslog).

Comment: Even better, the kernel will automatically take the "memtest" results into account and avoid using the damaged areas of the RAM till the next reboot. So you can just add "memtest" to your default boot parameters and the list of corrupted memory will always be up-to-date.

Comment: This isn't right. They're already avoided by default. It's in the docs _"reserves bad memory regions that are detected"_ you do not need badram.