# Disable corrupted memory

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, memory, ram

I have Supermicro servers and each server has 12 memory modules and `IPMI` interface. When I run `memtest86` on all my servers I detect some corrupted memories (channel X slot Y/Z). Also, I can find a little info in an IPMI log - which memory is corrupted on a motherboard ( for example P2 - C1 ). Hm Ok, if I had physical access to the server, I could power it down and replace the corrupted memory stick.

But what I need: when a memory corruption is detected through IPMI and I have not a physical access to the server (because the server is a half of a day away), without restarting the server I need to deactivate memory stick/slot/cell so the server will not crash (again). I know I could use `memmap` if I knew the index of the corrupted cell of the corrupted memory stick. But can I get the index from the IPMI log or Linux? Or if I know which memory stick is corrupted, can I deactivate the whole stick or slot from in Linux or IPMI?

Comment: As far as I know the Linux kernel has no way of forcing your memory allocations to any physical address.

Comment: It has! First, you can trick memtester to allocate the bad region, as described in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624678/52236) answer. There is also a tools named "lsmem" and "chmem" in the util-linux, although it somehow does not work on my systems.