# How to get the mapping between physical and virtual memory page addresses in Linux/Amd64?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

I would like to know, which **physical** pages are being mapped by induvidual processes.

`/proc/<pid>/maps` shows the virtual address mapping. I think it would be a good start, if I could somehow discover the relation between the physical and virtual memory pages.

Comment: Side result: I found this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt It seems, /proc/<pid>/pagemap can show a virtual -> physical mapping, but it has a binary format. Some tool might be able to read it. I think such a tool could answer the question.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the information? (How consistent do you need it to be?) The issue is that the mapping changes frequently over time (page faults, reclaim, migration, samepage merging, etc…), so it's going to be fairly hard to extract a consistent snapshot of the page tables without very controlled circumstances (which basically amount to what the PM code does to freeze userspace and most kernel activity).

Comment: @TooTea There are some faulty pages in my RAM, I want to lock them. The user-space memtester tool can show the physical address location, and it can be tricked to lock a specific physical page range. However, sometimes it can not lock. I think some of the faulty pages are used by processes. I want to find these processes, and kill/restart them in the hope that they will use other pages next time. So I will be able to lock the faulty locations in my RAM.

Comment: @TooTea Thus, I believe, a very consistent snapshot is not needed - if the page becomes used again after the virtual table dump, then the tricked memtester tool will fail again (so then I will re-run and we are okay). My [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624678/52236) answer is about the trick: I simply start the memtester tool to check *only* the faulty region, and then I simply suspend it. Yes, yes, I know it is very dirty, but imagine, how useful can be this workaround, if you can not reboot a remote server with a bad ram on the spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/pid/pagemap` is likely what you need if you're just curious. (So you don't mind if you don't get a fully consistent snapshot of the mapping.)

To interpret the data in there in a more user-friendly fashion, take a look at [How to decode /proc/pid/pagemap entries in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021214/how-to-decode-proc-pid-pagemap-entries-in-linux) or this random set of tools that Google just gave me (no endorsement): https://github.com/dwks/pagemap